# When is a nested sequence of closed sets a colimit?

Tags: gn.general-topology, gt.geometric-topology, limits-and-colimits

Let $X$ denote a topological space and $X_0\subset X_1\subset \ldots\subset X$ a nested sequence of closed subsets of $X$ such that $$ \bigcup_i X_i =X$$

It is easy to see that in the general case $X$ is not the colimit over these $X_i$, i.e. that a function $f\colon X\to Y$ is continuous if and only if $f|_{X_i}$ is continuous. Take for example $X=\mathbb{Q}$ and $X_i= \{\sigma(0),\ldots \sigma(i)\}$ for some enumeration of $\mathbb{Q}$. But of course $\mathbb{Q}$ isn't such a nice space after all.

So my question is what are sufficent and easy to prove conditions on $X$ such that $X$ is the colimit over this sequence of subsets.

The case of particular interest for me is, where $X$ is the space of embeddings between two manifolds and the $X_i$ measure some kind of irregularity of these embeddings..

Comment: Everything depends on the concrete $X$ and its topology. Of course you can introduce a new stronger co-limit topology ojn $X$ but then probably will lose good algeraic properties of $X$.